# Android Firebase - Twitter signin button not even making sound

Tags: android, firebase, twitter

I just switched from Facebook auth to Twitter auth.  Facebook worked fine, but now that I have this twitter button on my login screen, it won't even make a sound when I click it.  Does anybody have any ideas?  Is there something that I should put in my manifest to enable this to work properly?  I have updated API and Secret keys as well.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{




private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;


private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity.class";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET"))
            .debug(true)
            .build();
    Twitter.initialize(config);


    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {


            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging you in");
            progressDialog.show();
            handleTwitterSession(result.data);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure

            System.out.println("failed for some reason");
        }
    });



    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void handleTwitterSession(TwitterSession session) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleTwitterSession:" + session);

    AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
            session.getAuthToken().token,
            session.getAuthToken().secret);

    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        checkUserAndStart();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}

private void checkUserAndStart(){
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("bio");
    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }else{
                finish();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateProfileActivity.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

and bellow is my simple login button layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/baseColor"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.morticia.android.pop.activities.LoginActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"

        android:padding ="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/maincircmdpi"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4" />


        <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks
-T

Answer (score 0):

Rookie move.

`Twitter.initialize(this);` needs to be above setContentView();

added that at the top and now it works fine.

removed this:

```
    TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
        .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
        .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET"))
        .debug(true)
        .build();
Twitter.initialize(config);
```

-T